# Word for saying that some media content has been shortened in length?

Tags: adjectives

What word can I use to describe a song or a movie that has been shortened or edited to a smaller sample of it's original content/length?

Comment: ***abridged*** ?

Answer (score 3):

The term yo are looking for is ***[abridged](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abridged):***

> shortened or condensed especially by the omission of words or passages.
>
> - *an abridged dictionary an abridged version/edition of a classic novel*.

(M-W)

[image]